# Setting debounce lodash when a function has several arguments

Tags: javascript, lodash

When I don't have  parameters in function I set `debounce` in this way: `search = debounce ((query) => this.getTask(query), 1000);`. And how to set `debounce` when I have several parameters?

```
  search = debounce ((query) => {
     this.setState ({
       query
     }, () => this.getTask(userId, query, status)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of parameters doesn't make a difference to `debounce`, it will pass everything to your function.

```js
const search = _.debounce((param1, param2) => {
  console.log(param1);
  console.log(param2);
}, 1000);

search('hi', 'hello');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `search = debounce ((query) => {
     this.setState ({
       query
     }, () => this.getTask(userId, query, status)
}, 1000)`   ?